# How can I create a new field with a line break in it?

Tags: entities

I created a few fields which always stick together with no free space at all.
Then I created a new field between them which I named linebrake, chose the "long text and summary" (which is the only type where I can add html-code) and wrote `<br>` (`<p></p>` doesn't work) and now I have like 3 line breaks at once.

Is there any way to get only 1 line break?

Thanks in advance

Comment: you should be able to theme the specific fields in CSS. A screenshot of what is happening as well the field names will help give you an answer

Comment: this is what happens @ the frontend when using the "br"-tag: 
http://img177.imagevenue.com/img.php?image=175607647_screenshotfrontend_122_600lo.jpg 

I guess I should look into the css-files

here are the field_names I used for the line_breaks the other are title, original title, picture and bidy: (they are German)
http://img165.imagevenue.com/img.php?image=175605496_screenshotbackend_122_417lo.jpg

Answer (score 0):

Maybe the "p" tag doesn't work, because has been escaped and the Text format chosen is "Filtered HTML", see the "Allowed HTML tags" below to be sure that the "p" tag is allow.

Choose "Full HTML" for not escape.

Greetings.

Comment: the "p" tag is not working although I chose "full html" http://img165.imagevenue.com/img.php?image=175605496_screenshotbackend_122_417lo.jpg

Answer (score 0):

Basically it depend on the `Text format` you choose.

`Filtered html` strips most of your tags, so it can be the issue.

You can test it by choosing `phpcode`  or `Full html` in your text format dropdown. You can insert one line spacing by pressing shift+ENTER(if editor enabled) or using 
.

If you still face the issue check Text Format setting in your `Configuration settings`.

Hope it will help you!

Comment: there is a checkmark in the option "convert linebrakes into html ("br" and "p") ... has to be the css I guess

Comment: yes it must be checked